# The constructor JDABuilder(AccountType) is deprecated

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

In JDA i keep getting the error "The constructor JDABuilder(AccountType) is deprecated"

```
package diaduck.Playground;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.AccountType;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;

public class Main {
    public static JDA jda;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        jda = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT).setToken("**************************").buildAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation tells you what to do.

Answer (score 1):

This constructor has been deprecated for well over a year now. The documentation tells you exactly why and what needs to be done. In fact, this constructor no longer even exists on the latest version of JDA.

The migration guide tells you to use the new factory methods instead. Read more on [GitHub](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/0%29-Migrating-to-V4#jdabuilder-and-defaultshardmanagerbuilder)